# Masonry like bootstrap column getting chopped off

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

here i am using trying to get the pintrest like layout. here i am using bootstrap column grid to show results in page.

when i add the my css i am able to get the layout but the `div` column is getting chopped off at the end

here is my code

css:

```
row {
 -moz-column-width: 16em;
 -webkit-column-width: 16em;
 -moz-column-gap: 0.21em;
 -webkit-column-gap:0.21em; 

}

.item {
 display: inline-block;
 padding:  0.1rem;
 width:  100%; 
}
```

Html:

```
<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3 item'>
<div class='panel panel-warning'><div class='panel-heading'>Numark Ns7Ii 4-Channel Motorized Dj Controller And Mixer</div>
<div class='panel-body'><span class='price'>Walden: &#8377; 24000/-</span>
<a href="product-description.php?3"><br><br><img class='product_listing_img img-responsive' src=files/uploaded_images/Numark.jpg><br></a>
<h4>MRP: <span>&#8377;<strike>119852</strike></span></h4><a href='#' class='buy-button btn btn-warning col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span> Add to cart</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the output i am getting

[image]

you can see the 2nd and 3rd column item getting chopped in top

how can i solve this?

Comment: Just a suggestion, this has been done many times.. like this https://gist.github.com/justincarroll/5959773

Comment: The HTML you've provided is not enough to reproduce the issue. Please provide enough HTML to demonstrate the problem.